# How do the quantities of ATP formed during aerobic and anaerobic respiration compare?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology

How do the quantities of ATP formed during aerobic and anaerobic respiration compare?

Comment: What do you mean by compare? The amount of ATP made in each process? Is this a homework question?

Comment: @Aly I guess you are referring to glycolysis and its [switch to lactic fermentation in anaerobic conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycolysis)?

Answer (score 3):

You means fermentation and respiration? 
In aerobic,1 mol glucose trough respiration and get about 38 ATP
In anaerobic, 1 mol glucose through fermentaion and get 2 ATP

Comment: I think you mean 1 molecule, not 1 mol.

Comment: Yes! I means that.